# Passing variable between class methods

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to pass variables from a while loop into another method from a different class. I am new to OOP so I am unsure how to do this I have been googling for a while now with no luck. My code is below:

```
class ImageRenderer extends CommentReplyRenderer {

    function __construct() {
        $comments = new ImageIterator();
        $test = $comments->getAll();
        while($id = $test->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $id['photo_id'];
        }
    }
}
```

The above class has the variable that I need to pass `$id['photo_id']` into the below method.

```
class CommentIterator extends CommentReplyIterator
{
    public $conn;
    public $idOfComment;
    public $stmt;

    public function getAll($idOfComment)
    {   
        $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `photo_id` = :picture_id');
        $this->stmt->bindValue(':picture_id', $idOfComment);
        $this->stmt->execute();

        return $this->stmt;

    }
}
```

The variable needs to be placed inside the argument `$idOfComment` given to the `getAll()` method. I am calling it like this for now until I figure out how to pass it:

```
$comment1 = new CommentIterator();
$testing = $comment1->getAll($id['photo_id']);
while($boom = $testing->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $boom['comment'];
}
```

You can see that I am trying to place it inside the line `$testing = $comment->getAll($id['photo_id']);` but I get an undefined variable error.

Class I am extending the `CommentReplyRenderer` does not have anything in it

```
class CommentReplyIterator
{
    public $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', 'test','BOOMSHAKALAKA');
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            echo'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the classes you're extending?

Comment: Still not seeing anything obvious. Can you post the error message?

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: id in /var/www/EncoreCMS/designPatterns/Comments.php on line 105`

Comment: You're instantiating `ImageIterator` but calling a method in `CommentIterator`